# Apache Spark 3.1.2 can't read from S3 via documented spark-hadoop-cloud

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3

The spark docmentation suggests using `spark-hadoop-cloud` to read / write from S3 in https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cloud-integration.html .

There is no apache spark published artifact for spark-hadoop-cloud. Then when trying to use the Cloudera published module the following exception occurs

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(boolean, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)'
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.lookupPassword(S3AUtils.java:894)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.lookupPassword(S3AUtils.java:870)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.getEncryptionAlgorithm(S3AUtils.java:1605)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:363)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3303)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:124)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3352)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3320)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:479)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:361)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.hasMetadata(FileStreamSink.scala:46)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:377)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:325)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:519)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:428)
```

This seems like a classpath conflict. Then it seems like it's not possible to use spark-hadoop-cloud to read with the vanilla apache spark 3.1.2 jars

```
version := "0.0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.12"

lazy val app = (project in file("app")).settings(
    assemblyPackageScala / assembleArtifact := false,
    assembly / assemblyJarName := "uber.jar",
    assembly / mainClass := Some("com.example.Main"),
    // more settings here ...
  )

resolvers += "Cloudera" at "https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.1.1" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.1.1" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hadoop-cloud" % "3.1.1.3.1.7270.0-253"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "3.1.1.7.2.7.0-184"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "3.1.1.7.2.7.0-184"
libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-bundle" % "1.11.901"

libraryDependencies += "com.github.mrpowers" %% "spark-daria" % "0.38.2"
libraryDependencies += "com.github.mrpowers" %% "spark-fast-tests" % "0.21.3" % "test"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.1" % "test"
```

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object SparkApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]){
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local")
      //.config("spark.jars.repositories", "https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/")
      //.config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.spark:spark-hadoop-cloud_2.12:3.1.1.3.1.7270.0-253")
      .appName("spark session").getOrCreate

    val jsonDF = spark.read.json("s3a://path-to-bucket/compact.json")
    val csvDF = spark.read.format("csv").load("s3a://path-to-bucket/some.csv")
    jsonDF.show()
    csvDF.show()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read and write to S3 from Spark you only need these 2 dependencies:

```
"org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % hadoopVersion, 
"org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % hadoopVersion
```

Make sure the haddopVersion is the same used by your worker nodes and make sure your workers node also have these dependencies available. The rest of your code looks correct.

Comment: Thank you. 

iirc I have previously seen the use of hadoop-aws through an IDE using a local master and without the spark binary distribution but by providing jars. . If possible this makes the source tree more portable. So my preference is to make this work without depending on the binary distribution and spark submit, but expect that we should also be able to run against a cluster.

Finally it seems that more robust support regarding configuration utilizes the spark-hadoop-cloud jar so an ideal solution would support using this dependency.

Comment: Downloading spark source tree and setting the hadoop version and I am able to run locally.

Comment: spark team is going to release that spark-hadoop-cloud with new releases, it was not done before for various reasons.